# Arduino light blinking not working after stopping node.js program

Tags: node.js, arduino, johnny-five

i am new in arduino, but i do have knowledge of Node.js.

recently i brought arduino uno board. i have tried basic/hello world program of arduino which is LED light blinking, for that i am using jhonny-five.js.

i have plugged arduino board to my laptop, then i uploaded firmata to board and then i run node.js program on my laptop it is working fine, LED light is blinking. every thing is working like charm.

but when i stops the node.js program then LED light stop blinking. basically i want to do that when i just power-up the board, it should run LED blinking functionality.

right now i need to plugin device, then run that node.js program. this way it is working.but is there any way where i just plug arduino board and it automatically runs LED blinking functionality without running node.js code on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firmata library is exactly for receiving commands over Serial port. So you can run code on your computer and commands that must be executed in Arduino are sent there. But without that program, it's just waiting for commands, so it does "nothing".

If you wan't stand-alone program, you have to use Arduino IDE and upload code directly.

Comment: you means i have to write code in C language? so i can upload whole code to arduino board, m i right?

Comment: Arduino Code is C++. You can find Blink example in Arduino IDE Examples / 01.Basics /  Blink